# Regex to add a space after the fourth chars Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string which is a car number plate. But for display purposes I what to add a space after the fourth char in this string. The data comes from a data service so I have to do this on the front-end

eg. AF13BXP to this AF13 BXP

The code below doesn't seem to work:

```
var $regtext = $('#regNumber');
if ($regtext.length > 0)
{
    var regtext = $regtext.text(),
    newRegtext = regtext.replace(/[\n\s]/g, '');
    console.log(newRegtext);
}
```

Comment: How your posted code is relevant to your question? BTW, it works or not, quite ambiguous

Comment: sounds great. Now tell us what is the problem?

Comment: `newRegtext = regtext.replace(/(^.{4})/, "$1 ")`

Comment: I updated the question sorry it didn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple and clear way to do this, without regex:

```
var $regtext = $('#regNumber');

if ($regtext.length > 0)
{
    var regtext = $regtext.text(),
    newRegtext = regtext.substr(0, 4) + " " + regtext.substr(4);
    console.log(newRegtext);
}
```

It's also pretty fast too: runs 10,000 times in 351ms, faster than splitting and joining etc. Good if you'll be processing loads of data from the webservice.

Comment: Great :) On here you accept the answer (click the tick) if it answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following jquery : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/juspC/185/)

```
$('.test').keyup(function() {
  var foo = $(this).val().split(" ").join(""); 
  if (foo.length > 0) {
    foo = foo.match(new RegExp('.{1,4}', 'g')).join(" ");
  }
  $(this).val(foo);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex the following should do it.

newRegtext = regtext.replace(/^(.{4})/,'$1 ')

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
    var $regtext = $('#regNumber');
    var $regtext = $regtext.text();
    if ($regtext.length > 0)
    {

regCheck = /^([A-Z1-9a-z]{1,4})([A-Z1-9a-z]*)$/;
regtext = regCheck.test($regtext);
  newRegtext = $regtext.replace(regCheck,"$1 $2");
        alert(newRegtext);

    }
  });
```